# How can I make an irregular shaped cube

Tags: edit-mode

Is there an easy method to create an irregular shaped cube (only the X and Y axis) such as the image below with sides of particular lengths and particular angles.
I have also included my object but need to know how I can apply particular angles where each adjacent edges intersect.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why not just edit the vertices? What is the shape you're trying to achieve? (your image shows a plane, not a tridimensional object)

Comment: Thanks. I know of editing vertices but never tried and didn't know if it was possible to result in sides of particular lengths and also internal angles. Yes the image is a plane as I created with a (2D) image editor. I have added an image of what I am trying to model.   It would make it easier for me if I could place an image in the workspace to use as a template to drag the vertices to. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, you can import an image as a reference. Go in top view (Numpad 7), then add the image with Shift+A > Add > Image > Reference. Add a plane, and edit the vertices. To create a "cube" just extrude all verts along the Z-axis. This gives the building some height. I hope this is what your question is about.

Comment: Thanks. That is really great and will make duplicating the dock (in shape and dimensions) so much easier

Comment: Adding the 'Image Reference' made creating my object (part of floating dock) quite simple after first scaling the image to have the top (2D) dimensions close to the actual real dock. Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops! I didn't follow your instructions completely using a cube instead of a plane and ended up with an empty box (bottom and sides only).

Comment: You should definitely try to follow a few beginner-level courses (plenty available on youtube for free) before diving into more complicated stuff, will save you a lot of headache

Comment: Well I have now been learning Blender for 8 weeks using youtube videos and I would hardly call myself a beginner already having created a number of objects. I have lost count on how many videos I have watched and also read a large part of a Blender 'manual'. The big problem I have is breaking a task down to smaller parts, knowing what 'features' on Blender are there to use and thinking logically how to create an object 'from the ground up. And sometimes its just finding a video tutorial which helps NOT to mentioned the fact that so many are based on 2.8 which often doesn't 'look like' 2.9!

Comment: Lastly I have lost count of the number of video tutorials I have tried to watch but because of the low resolution I cannot read the print on the screen.